# How to output chrome driver version as a string in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way in powershell to output the chrome driver version in powershell?
Can I find the chrome driver in the registry?

I am looking for something like:

```
$chromeDriver = SOME_FUNCTION()
Write-Host $chromeDriver
```

output should be something like:

```
90.0.4430.212
```

Comment: If it's installed in your path it will be discoverable with `Get-Command chromedriver.exe` (that should also tell you the file version)

Comment: my chrome driver is installed in C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe
I cd to that directory, ran that command, and it didn't work.

Comment: `Get-Command .\chromedriver.exe` <- if you're trying to look in the current directory

Comment: It doesn't look to me like Chromedriver includes the version metadata in the executable. At least they don't in 90.0.4430.24. Short answer: You don't.

Comment: It does look like you can run `.\chromedriver.exe --version`, however.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon "Bacon Bits" Comment

`& $ChromDriverPath --version;`

should return the full version.